# Primary key column isn't in GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

I have this query:

```
SELECT foo, bar, MIN(baz)
    FROM foos
    WHERE bazzbazz = 'default'
    GROUP BY foo, bar;
```

It gives the desired resultset, with the different `foo`/`bar` combinations and their respective lowest `baz` in the table.

However, I also want to get the primary key (`id`) for each row in the same query. When I add `id` to my `SELECT`, I receive an error saying that `id` is not in GROUP BY. This is how the query looks like:

```
SELECT foo, bar, MIN(baz), id
    FROM foos
    WHERE bazzbazz = 'default'
    GROUP BY foo, bar;
```

To avoid the error I can add `id` to `GROUP BY`. But then, I just get every possible row in the resultset rather than only the minimum `baz` for `foo` and `bar`. I cannot seem to be able to use `WHERE baz = MIN(baz)`.

How should I modify the query to also get `id` without removing the SQL mode `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`?

Comment: What `id`? There are more than one for each group

Comment: @juergend the `id` of the row that has `baz` as its minimum value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a `JOIN` to the table of `MIN` values, adding `baz = MIN(baz)` as a `JOIN` condition:

```
SELECT f1.*
FROM foos f1
JOIN (SELECT foo, bar, MIN(baz) AS baz
      FROM foos
      GROUP BY foo, bar) f2 ON f2.foo = f1.foo AND f2.bar = f1.bar AND f2.baz = f1.baz
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9Ky9yMZvNu6uJVikXeGJYf/0)

Comment: This query seems to run just about instantly compared to 200ms run time of the other answer. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @shavit that's because a correlated subquery in a `WHERE` clause runs the subquery for *every* row of the table, whereas this runs the derived table query once.

Answer (score 0):

use correlated subquery

```
SELECT foo, bar, baz, id
    FROM foos a
    WHERE bazzbazz = 'default' and baz in (select MIN(baz) from foos b where a.foo=b.foo and a.baz=b.baz)
```